# Cases where float == and != are not direct opposites

Tags: c, ieee-754, comparison-operators

In https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6428, the root cause for the bug seems to be that at [`simd.inc.src:543`](https://github.com/juliantaylor/numpy/blob/a62abc814584047e22a630c92fe355783a5e9fc7/numpy/core/src/umath/simd.inc.src#L543), a compiler optimizes `!(tmp == 0.)` to `tmp != 0.`.

[A comment](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6428#issuecomment-146975795) says that these are "not quite the same thing." But doesn't specify any details. NaNs are mentioned further on, but a test shows that a NaN compares to `0.` the expected way.

**What are the cases where `==` and `!=` can both return true/false?**

**Or the discrepancy is in another field** - e.g. returning values that have the same truth value but are different as ints (but testing shows even this doesn't seem the case)**?**

Comment: If `f` can be `NaN`, it isn't an `int`.

Comment: Nan cant become 0. Since 0 is a Number, and  NaN means not a number. so your saying if you do this `int a = 0 ;` a is a NaN?

Comment: Excuse me if I'm missing something obvious, but: Where in that thread do they identify that as the root cause? The closest reference I see begins with "I'm going to guess"! Anyway, this linked bug seems closer: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/6438

Comment: *What are the cases where == and != can both return true/false?* - Return `true` or both `false` for the same operands in the same program? Never...

Comment: @underscore_d The author says it's a guess but they are quite positive that `!(tmp==0)` and `tmp!=0` are not equivalent and express that as if it's common knowledge. That's what the question is basically about. I edited the question to emphasize this focus.

Comment: Crystal ball says that the MSVC9 build used /fp:fast.  Everybody likes fast, except unit tests.

Comment: In case it's relevant, juliantaylor wrote "the difference for 64 bit is probably that it doesn't use the x87 fpu which will lead to different code generation"

Comment: What makes you think the comment is correct?

Comment: @4386427 the fact it's from someone who's more knowledgeable in the subject than me (a numpy maintainer) and sounds pretty confident in the statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A comment says that these are "not quite the same thing." But doesn't specify any details. NaNs are mentioned further on, but a test shows that a NaN compares to 0. the expected way.
>
> **What are the cases where == and != can both return true/false?**

The standard says:

> The `==` (equal to) and `!=` (not equal to) operators are analogous to the relational operators except for their lower precedence.  [...]  ***For any  pair of operands, exactly one of the relations is true.***

(C2011, 6.5.9/3; emphasis added)

Therefore, for any expressions X and Y that are jointly allowed as operands of these operators, `(X) != (Y)` must evaluate to the same result as `!((X) == (Y))`.  If they are found in practice not to do so, then the compiler that yielded that result is non-conforming in that respect.  If that non-conformance is unexpected, then it constitutes a bug in the compiler.

Additionally, I observe that 6.5.9/3 applies just as much to NaNs, infinities, and subnormals as to any other operands.  NaNs are special with respect to these operators for a different reason: NaNs compare unequal to all operands, including themselves (supposing IEEE semantics).

Comment: Okay, it looks like I ultimately have to [call the comment's author out on their statement](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6428#issuecomment-231404458) to end this charade.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev It may be possible that the code is being compiled with `-ffast-math` or such in which case the behaviour might not exactly be correct.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, FUZxxl's example would be a case where the compiler is non-conforming, but not buggy, as it documents that using the option may cause non-conformance (and that's also why the behavior has to be explicitly enabled via an option).  Do note that the numpy bug cited is related to the MSVC build, and MSVC is notorious for being both non-conforming and buggy.

Comment: @JohnBollinger there's no place for FUD here. [The assembly code for both working and non-working cases is given](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6428#issuecomment-146951364) and both seem correct at first glance.

Comment: The comment's author never responded. So, the case can be closed, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

From the linked post:

> charris commented on Oct 9, 2015
>
> I'm going to guess the `!(tmp == 0.)` is optimized to `tmp != 0.`, which is not quite the same thing.

Comment by the OP:

> The author says it's a guess but they are quite positive that `!(tmp==0.)` and `tmp!=0.` are not equivalent and express that as if it's common knowledge

How do we reconcile these two?

Clearly, they are **logically** equivalent.  But implementation-wise, they may not be.  A compiler might implement `!(a == b)` as the test `a == b` followed by a negation.  Alternately, it might optimize the expression, and directly test `a != b`.  Resulting assembly code would be different in those two cases.  The same result should (must) be achieved, but the execution time could be different.

"not quite the same thing" would simply be an acknowledgement that `!(a == b)` and `a != b` are actually different combinations of characters and the compiler might do something technically different with them, that must yield the same result.  And if different results are observed, then a bug might exist in the compiler.

Comment: What are you saying? They have to return the same result. How the CPU gets there is of no consequence. Anything else is a compiler bug. Then "The same result should (must) be achieved, but the execution time could be different." - which would cause so many tests to fail because...?

Comment: @underscore_d I'm saying the OP misinterpreted charris's "which is not quite the same" comment.  charris is talking about implementation differences, and the OP read it as logical equivalence.  All this is complicated by a difference in result actually being observed, contrary to both party's expectations.  The OP is trying to figure out under what case the logical equivalence breaks down, based on charris's comment.  But charris comment was not regarding the logical equivalence of the two tests, but the resulting implementation of the tests.